# How to put text below the cover image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following effect. An image that looks like a background is placed in the top 60% of the page. If the image is unproportional, it should keep correct aspect ratio.

After this image some other text goes.

I achieved the first half with

```
#fullcover{
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(img);
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    max-height: 60%;
}
```

but the problem is that my text is now hiding behind my image. How can I put it exactly below? [JsFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tr4DW/).

Sorry for not including this in the first place: I would rather not use html, body 100%.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Tr4DW/5/?

Comment: use z-index-10000; for your text

Comment: @j08691 exactly like this, but I do not really like overwritting rules for html and body

Comment: @SalvadorDali Why not? You need to use a css reset if you want your site to look same in all browsers.

Comment: You don't have to overwrite your html and body rules (unless they already have a height). You can just add the height rule and the padding/margin are optional.

Comment: @Prashank I have not seen that in css-reset people are adding html, body 100% http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/

Comment: I didn't mean resets need a height, i was just making a point that theres nothing wrong with adding css for html, body elements

Comment: @Prashank thanks. Now I got it, I am just telling that I would rather not use html, body 100%.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I don't understand the reason but if you really don't want to then you have to position things "absolute"...which is given in one of the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tr4DW/1/)

If you know that the image willonly take up the top portion of the site, you can place the text object with an absolute position with the top at 60%.

```
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
```

And remove:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

That should fix the issue! and make your code cleaner. Also, you have an extra closing bracket at the very end of the stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this but does this one works for you?

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
#fullcover{
    background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-eL9c6lkgTfA/TYgOwVna0WI/AAAAAAAAA8I/DpU04ZImGF8/s1600/beautiful%2Bfish3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    max-height: 60%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/G3J5K/3/)

Comment: This is exactly the way I want it to look. The only problem is that I would rather not overwrite html and body tags

Comment: you're not overriding anything, i would even recommend to use a css reset http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
#fullcover{
position:absolute;
background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-eL9c6lkgTfA/TYgOwVna0WI/AAAAAAAAA8I/DpU04ZImGF8/s1600/beautiful%2Bfish3.jpg);
top: 0; 
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
max-height: 60%;
z-index:-1;
}
```

this places the text ontop of the fish image if you want it to be below the fish image do this:

```
.text {

  color:#000;
  margin-top:25%;


  }
```